# Plotting Multiple Regression

Tags: regression, linear-regression

We have to do multiple regression for a college project. We have all the data, but we don't know, how to plot it and how[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcFJu.png) to draw a regression line.
[Our current programming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcFJu.png)

Comment: I suggest  you add  lnaguage tag and post the actual code you have tried, rather thana a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to R, try the visreg pacakge. Suppose you you have 3 explanatory variables in your model:

```
library(visreg)
lm.result <- lm(povred~lnenp+maj+pr)
```

Since you have 3 variables, visreg would produce 3 plots. In each plot the other two variables are held at mean. So you first want to define a 2x2 space for plots:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

Then just ask visreg to plot your lm result:

```
visreg(lm.result)
```

[This is how the plots should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya9NF.png)